# Product Rule for Derivatives. Where am I erring? $x = (2 + 2\cos\theta)(\cos \theta) $

Tags: calculus

I have an equation:

$x = (2 + 2\cos\theta)(\cos \theta) $. If I take the derivative, $ \frac {dx}{d\theta} $, through the product rule, I get: $ (-2\sin\theta)(\cos\theta) + (2 + 2\cos\theta)(- \sin\theta)$

However, if I multiply out first, getting $ 2\cos\theta + 2\cos^2\theta$ and then take the derivative, I get $ \frac{dx}{d\theta} = -2\sin\theta - 4\cos\theta \sin\theta$ .

How are these two equal?

Comment: $$(-2sin\theta)(\cos\theta) + (2 + 2\cos\theta)(- \sin\theta)$$
$$=-2\sin\theta\cos\theta-2\sin\theta-2\sin\theta\cos\theta=-4\sin\theta\cos\theta-2\sin\theta$$

Comment: I have no clue as to "why the downvote"?  Haim showed the original problem, his work differentiating (correctly) twice.  OP simply wants to reconcile to see that in fact, the two are equal...No error...formatted nicely, save for forgetting the backslash in front of trig functions (but then, look at first comment, it happens to the best of us.)  The question is crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

When expanding the first one and combining like terms, you get the second one. Also, I think you mean the product rule, not the power rule (you say power rule in your question but product rule in the title).

Answer (score 1):

Your only error is stopping a step to early; you did all the work, except using your algebra skills to see that that we can work with either  equation to get the other.

So we have, as you obtained using the product rule:  $$\begin{align} \frac {dx}{d\theta}  &= (-2\sin\theta)(\cos\theta) + \color{blue}{(2 + 2\cos\theta)(- \sin\theta)} \\ \\ 
& = -2\sin\theta\cos\theta + \color{blue}{-2\sin\theta- 2\sin\theta\cos\theta}\\\\
& =  -4\sin\theta\cos\theta  - 2\cos\theta\end{align}\\\\$$

This is the result you obtained using the second procedure, essentially, algebra then the chain rule.